# How to get data extracted in an array through each loop in JQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML Code:

```
<form onSubmit="return false;" id="patientPastHistory">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        Past History
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="medicalCondition" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="Medical Condition">
                                            <label for="medicalCondition">E.g. Asthama, Arthiritis, etc.</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="medicalStatus">
                                        <option selected disabled value="">Select Treatment Status</option>
                                        <option value="Treated">Treated</option>
                                        <option value="Ongoing">Ongoing Treatment</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <a id="btnAdd" class="btn green-meadow mt-repeater-btn-inline btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table id="medicalCondition" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="60%"> Medical Condition </th>
                                        <th width="30%"> Status </th>
                                        <th width="10%"> Action </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="treatmentTbl">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        {{-- Submit Button --}}
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2  mt-35">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                                <button id="btnpatientPastHistory" class="fwb btn btn-circle green-meadow">
                                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Changes</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                                <button id="cancel" type="button" class="fwb btn btn-circle btn-outline dark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this table i am appending the data taken from an input filed via JQuery this is the code:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function()
    {
        var count = $("#treatmentTbl tr").length + 1;
        var medicalCondition = $("#medicalCondition").val();
        var medicalStatus = $("#medicalStatus").val();

        if (medicalCondition != "")
            {
                if (medicalStatus == "Treated")
                    {
                        $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id="+count+"><td data-name="+medicalCondition+">"+medicalCondition+"</td><td><span class='label label-success' data-name="+medicalStatus+">"+medicalStatus+"</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id="+count+"><td data-name="+medicalCondition+">"+medicalCondition+"</td><td><span class='label label-danger' data-name="+medicalStatus+">"+medicalStatus+"</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
                    }

                $("#medicalCondition").val('');
                $("#medicalStatus").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            }
    });
```

This is my Custom JQuery code to take the data that is being reflected in the table to send to the server:

```
$("button#btnpatientPastHistory").click(function()
    {
        var data = [];
        var dataAttributes = ["medicalCondition: ", "treatmentStatus:"];

        $('table#medicalCondition > tbody#treatmentTbl  > tr > td').each(function(i)
            {
                data.push(dataAttributes[i]+$(this).data("name"));

                if(i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        data.push(dataAttributes[i]+$(this > 'span').data("name"));
                    }
            });

        console.log(data);
    });
```

What I am trying to do is I am trying to take the data from the table and dump it into an array variable means like there will an array data like `dataArray = []` then I want to store data in this like if 1st data in the table is stored then there should be an index created with [1] inside the dataArray and then the 1st tr row data is to be stored in it and so on until the data finishes.

But somehow I am not able to do that I have used my logic so far in the above JQuery code posted but I don't know most of the time it gives an error in the console of NAN. Can anyone help me with this logic?

Comment: As i have given data-name='some value that is being inputted via user' so as soon as user click on the plus button the data will be added in the table

Comment: I suggest you to try to add like attributes passed to the anonymal function both index and value, I think this behavior can be generated for the only attribute you use in the function... is the index or the value?

Comment: Means how and what should i add in the code and where ?

Comment: when you use each function, for each element you have an anonymal function, this function have two parameters the index and the value, if you use only one of the two I don't know if this is the index or the value. `$('table#medicalCondition > tbody#treatmentTbl  > tr > td').each(function(i) ...` -> `$('table#medicalCondition > tbody#treatmentTbl  > tr > td').each(function(index, element) ...`

Comment: For debug I usually print in console every element processed by the function, this is for be sure that I'm processing the right elements

Comment: i even used your way like index and element still the same output :(

Comment: To be sure have you try to log every element processed?

Comment: Yes i have done that in console but it shows undefined everytime

Comment: Well, the problem can be caused from the selector, or by the use of `$(this)`, more times refers to unexpected values, use the variable `element` inside the anonimal function `function(index, element)`. Try also to use a more generical selector like `$(#treatmentTbl td)`, more times work....